# Efficiently synchronise two large sets of values in disparate databases

Tags: algorithm, synchronization, set-difference

I have a database table and a Lucene (possibly Solr) index. The goal is to index the database table, exactly one document per row. However:

1. The initial state of the Lucene index is unknown and may already be mostly synchronised. It may also contain documents for nonexistent rows, which will be removed afterwards via another mechanism.
2. The application doing the resync may need to restart multiple times during the process. Very little state can be stored across restarts (ideally none) so brute-forcing a set difference up-front isn't going to work.
3. Low-level access to the Lucene index is not allowed; I can run queries against it but can't eg. directly enumerate the terms in a given field. Looking up a key or counting keys in a range can be done with queries.
4. The rows in the database don't have any versioning info or ETags. We can assume that they're just a single column of unique keys.

It is not necessary to handle out-of-date or requires-deletion documents here. I just need to make sure that every row eventually has a document, with as little wasted time as possible.

Updating or deleting out-of-date documents is handled by a separate part of the system which may be assumed to run only *after* this resync mechanism has indicated completion. (In fact, a robust update/delete system was the easy bit...)

Previously this task was accomplished with a brute-force set difference, but this runs into difficulties with especially large sets of data and the solution really needs to take advantage of partial synchronisation in order to support resuming: if the application always makes some progress before it restarts it will eventually synchronise the stores.

The Difference Digest https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/EppGooUye-SIGCOMM-11.pdf looked interesting but seems to apply only in the case where the data stores have the necessary smarts to calculate it themselves. In this case, there's a single application doing the job and it can merely query, insert, and delete against the two stores.

So far, I'm thinking there are three basic cases here:

- The sets are wildly out of sync, eg. the index is empty. This should be easy enough to deal with simply by starting with the lowest ID of either set, querying a batch of records from the source, and adding/deleting differences in the destination. Unfortunately although this will make progress quickly initially, it will slow down as it spends longer 'catching up' after each restart.
- The sets are almost synchronised. It feels like there should be an efficient way of dealing with this, maybe by generating a histogram across the dataset and drilling down into individual buckets which don't 'match' the source, but it would still be necessary to visit every key and add it to some kind of bucket hash.
- The sets have a huge number of subtle differences, ie. same *number* of rows in each but ~60% of them have different keys. This seems like a worst-case scenario but it's not one that's particularly unlikely.

**Is there an established technique for solving this?** We do in fact use a sort of transaction log for recording what needs adding, but that's only able to handle normal operation, not initial sync or post-migration repairs.

I know there are products and systems out there which can handle this 'for me' but there are other implementation concerns which mean that this system *must* be implemented within the existing codebase at the moment, although it may be replaced with a more generic solution in the future. In fact, the whole point of this is to get the current system to a 'halfway house' in order to enable the use of other solutions.

I suppose the update/delete part of the system could be abused for the purposes of recording progress of a full scan, by adding placeholder documents which will get removed automatically when the process completes? I'd like to avoid the full scan when the sets are almost synced, though...